# How to find a value in data and then delete found column in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that receives a prompted response, searches for that value, and then deletes the given row or column. Here is the script that searches and deletes the row that works perfectly fine:

```js
function DeleteResources() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadhsheetID");
  // PROMPTS USER TO INSERT TASK NAME
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Name of Task:',
    '',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  // DELETES GIVEN TASK FROM RESOURCES
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(text)
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow();
  sheet.deleteRow(search_row);
};
```

Here is the modified version that searches for the value and deletes the column, but this one is not working properly:

```js
function DeleteDailyStatisticsRaw() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");
  // PROMPTS USER TO INSERT TASK NAME
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Name of Task:',
    '',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  // DELETES GIVEN TASK FROM DAILY STATISTICS RAW
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(text)
  var search_column = textFinder.findNext().getColumn();
  sheet.deleteColumn(search_column);
};
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just copied and pasted this into a test sheet and it worked no problem, are you sure your spreadsheet ID and sheet name are correct in your variables? Are you getting any specific error messages?

Comment: Yeah, just found out I was testing it wrong and linking the wrong ID. Thank you for the heads up and sorry about my mess up!